# CQWP bind sorting with query string

Tags: web-part, 2013, caml-query, content-query-web-part, sorting

Is there a way to use `PageQueryString` in CQWP to control the sort order and sort by behavior?

I am trying to implement this kind of sortable and filterable table with pagination:

[image: Sortable and Filterable table]

Would it be possible by tweaking OOTB CQWP?

I am using Twitter bootstrap from [responsive sharepoint framework](https://responsivesharepoint.codeplex.com/) and am trying to liverage this [table widget for bootstrap](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-bootstrap-theme.html).

Comment: If all information is stored in one single list, I would use the XsltListView webpart, it has built in functionality for all of this. And it looks and works exactly like a list view

Comment: @RobertLindgren, does it provide pagination, custom sorting and filtering (based on textbox and dropdowns value)?

Comment: It works just as a normal list view, so yes, yes, yes and yes yes yes yes yes. Just look at a normal list, that's the functionality you can get